# Error loading messages from .properties file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

I'm trying to have my project's Strings/ messages stored in an external `.properties` file. I think I have everything wired up OK, but still I get:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'subtype.user.client' for locale 'null'.
```

Whenever I try:

```
String string = messageSource.getMessage("subtype.user.client", null, null);
```

My spring xml config files are as follows. Since the project is really big with lots of beans, I have different spring xml config files defining different types of beans, and a main `spring.config.xml` file that wires them all together.

Messages file named `messages.subtypes`

```
subtype.user.user=User
subtype.user.client=Client props
subtype.user.staff=Staff
subtype.user.clerk=Clerk
subtype.user.secretary=Secretary
```

Messages beans file called `spring.messages.config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <list>
                <value>messages.subtypes</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myProjectLangs" class="myprojectbase.MyProjectLangs">
        <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The main `spring.config.xml` config file that wires all the beans together via `<import resource="classpath:filename.xml"/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <import resource="classpath:spring.messages.config.xml"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="myprojectbase"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Did you put the message file in the classpath or in maven resources folder?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. It is in the <default package>

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you pass the `Locale` parameter as null. Try

```
String string = messageSource.getMessage("subtype.user.client", null, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Even though you have not defined a file `messages.subtypes_en.properties` defined it should fall back to `messages.subtypes.properties`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things come to mind looking at your code any of which might  cause the problem:

- Your xml config name contains "." as separators. This is against conventions. Consider renaming your config file to spring-messages-config.xml
- Your language properties file has no properties suffix, again convention suggests to name this file messages-subtypes.properties
- In both your application context xml files you define a bean named `messageSource`. Consider deleting one of them.
- My prime suspicion as to why your code does not work lies with the way you define `basename` on `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. Looking at the JavaDoc for `setBasename` method there is some form of convention of configuration at work:

> Set a single basename, following the basic ResourceBundle convention of not specifying file extension or language codes, but in contrast to {@link ResourceBundleMessageSource} referring to a Spring resource location: e.g. "WEB-INF/messages" for "WEB-INF/messages.properties", "WEB-INF/messages_en.properties", etc. XML properties files are also supported: .g. "WEB-INF/messages" will find and load "WEB-INF/messages.xml", "WEB-INF/messages_en.xml", etc as well.

This suggests that once you have renamed your message properties file to `messages-subtypes.properties`, you should change your config to `<value>classpath:messages-subtypes</value>`, make sure that the file is in the classpath and everything should start working.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `messages.subtypes` file to `messages.subtypes.properties`.